# Creating GTM trigger/Linkedin Pixel tag for Drift chat click

Tags: google-tag-manager, linkedin-api, drift

I need to add a LinkedIn pixel to GTM to track Drift chat widget being clicked.

I have already added the LinkedIn pixel to a GTM tag, I know I did that correct. I created a GTM trigger that is set with the GTM tag and I'm having problems with the GTM tag not triggering. I have tried:

Trigger Configuration -> Trigger Type -> Click - All Elements

This trigger fires on -> Some Clicks -> Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true -> Click Classes -> equals -> [some class names I see when inspecting element]

The widget is placed inside an iframe. Should I assume any attempts to capture clicks from elements in the iframe will fail? When I "Preview" in GTM, view our site with the Tag Manager window open and then click the Drift chatbot widget - the GTM tag I created doesn't fire.

Comment: Is the iframe content served from the same or from a different domain?

Comment: Yes. It's not loaded via GTM.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get events from the iframe by default.

- the iframe is a separate, complete HTML page. If this is a third party widget, then it sounds like a safe bet that your GTM code is not embedded into that page, so you can catch events via the native GTM functions.
- as a third widget this runs most probably not on the same domain as your page. Cross-Domain communications with iframes is not something that happens by default (that's a security feature). If you can place Javascript into your widget, then you can communicate with your main page via [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (but then if you can place code you might be able to embed your GTM instance).

If Drift has something like tech support I would suggest to contact them - this is such a common issue that it's quite probable that they will have a solution ft it.